# Ruby won't write to file but won't print error

Tags: ruby, file-io

I'm writing a little memo script, and after running it and testing it, it doesn't output to the file, and it's making me pull out my hair as nothing I change fixes the problem. The file gets created, but stays empty.

```
require 'ruby-progressbar'
puts "Loading..."
lt = ProgressBar.create
if File.directory?("./memos") == false
    lt.progress = 50
    Dir.mkdir("memos")
    lt.progress = 100
end
lt.progress = 100
Dir.chdir("memos")
puts "Welcome to Eternal Memorizer."
loop do
    progress = ProgressBar.create
    progress.log "Getting files..."
    progress.progress = 50
    cdf = Dir.glob("**/*") 
    progress.progress = 100
    puts "Memos:"
    puts cdf
    puts ""
    puts "[M]ake memo, [R]ead memo, [D]elete memo."
    op = gets.chomp
    if op.downcase == "m"
        print "Memo name: "
        nam = gets.chomp
        puts "\nText, Press enter to finish:"
        txt = gets.chomp
        num = txt.length
        txt = txt.split('')
        ggg = ProgressBar.create(:title => "Saving...", :total => num)
        o = File.open("#{nam}.mem", 'w+')
        i = 0
        ggg.log "Writing #{txt.join}"
        num.times do
            puts txt
            #sleep(30)
            o.write("#{txt[i]}")
            i += 1
            ggg.increment
            ggg.title = "#{txt[i]}"
            #system("cls"); system("clear")
        end
    elsif op.downcase == "r"
        puts "Which memo to open?"
        fil = gets.chomp
        begin
            fil = File.open("#{fil}", 'r+')
            puts "\n-=-=-=-"
            puts fil.read
            puts "-=-=-=-\n"
        rescue
            puts "Err, unable to open file."
        end
    elsif op.downcase == "d"
        puts "Which memo to delete?"
        File.delete(gets.chomp)
    end
end
```

I've read and reread through it, and it's just hit the point where I've given up on it, so it'd be a big help if the error is found.

Comment: These variable names need a lot to be desired. Why the obsession with making them three letters? The names should be minimal, but descriptive. Like `fil` is confusing when `file`, just one letter long, is self-explanatory.

Comment: You should also learn to use `case`, as in `case op.downcase` and then simply `when 'm'`. It's a lot less code and a lot more efficient than downcasing the same thing repeatedly.

Answer (score 1):

Either close the file manually after you're done writing to it.

```
o.close
```

This should commit it to the disk.

Or use the block form of `File.open` which handles closing of the file.

```
File.open("#{nam}.mem", 'w+') do |o|
  i = 0
  ggg.log "Writing #{txt.join}"
  num.times do
      puts txt
      #sleep(30)
      o.write("#{txt[i]}")
      i += 1
      ggg.increment
      ggg.title = "#{txt[i]}"
      #system("cls"); system("clear")
  end
end
```

Comment: That worked, which is strange cause my other coding projects just wrote it and i didn't need to worry about closing it.

Comment: @Pixelz: nah, you __always__ need to close. But sometimes the system closes it for you.

Comment: Lol. The one time I make a serious program it changes the rules on me.